# Difference between parallel and series capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, electrical-resistance

Basically, I can't figure out that  whether a capacitor is connected in series or parallel.
The same problem occurs while solving for resistors. Can someone help me understand this difference conceptually?

Comment: My mantra is always, given 2 circuit elements (capacitors, resistors, etc.),  they are in series if ALL of the current that goes through one must also through the other.

Answer (score 1):

A parallel circuit is one where the current splits into two pathways at a point. An example is:

[image]

Here, the current in the loop splits into two.
Let's say that the battery produces a current of '$I$' $A$. It splits into two branches $i_1$ and $i_2$. Here:
$I = i_1 + i_2$

When this occurs, the circuits are said to be in parallel. This results in the *same potential difference* occuring across the two branches. So the potential difference across $R_1$ is equal to the potential difference across $R_2$.

---

The same idea is for Capacitors. When the potential difference across the plates is equal, they are in parallel. When the *current* through them is equal, they are in series.

[image]

Here, in circuit A, the capacitors are in series, while in B, they are in parallel.

---

Many a time, capacitors are represented in the following manner:

[image]

Here, the top circuit represents 3 capacitors in series. $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are the plates of the capacitors. Capacitor $AB$ is one, $BC$ is one and $CD$ is one.

The bottom circuit represents 3 capacitors in parallel. Since they're connected at the same 3 points, they have the same potential difference. The three capacitors are: Capacitor $AB$, capacitor $A'B'$ and capacitor $A''B''$. This notation is mostly used when different mediums are insterted into the capactitors - thus changing the $\epsilon_r$ value for each. Students wonder how to solve it further! It's easy - all of them are in parallel! :D

Hope I helped you understand!

Answer (score 0):

Let's deal with circuit elements (resistors, inductors, capacitors, batteries, meters) which have two connection ports.

Two components are connected in series when they are connected to each other only once and not connected to other components at that connection point, also called a \textbf{node} (IMPORTANT term). If a third component is in series with either of the first two, it is also in series with the other. They will have identical currents, but possibly different voltages.

[image: Series]

Elements A, B, and C are all in series

If any set (of any size) of circuit elements are connected to each other by both ports, but the two sides remain separate, the elements are in parallel.

[image: Parallel]

Here, B and C are in parallel with each other, but A is not in parallel, nor in series with either B or C.  The B/C parallel combination is in series with A.  If one port of a fourth element was connected  to the left end of B and the other port to the right end of B, then that fourth element would be in parallel with B and C.